# Trying to Launch Netbeans 12

Tags: java, netbeans

Recently installed Netbeans 12 along with the JDK and JRE Headless for the requirements to run Netbeans

I go to click on the Icon of Apache Netbeans and nothing happens to I launch it in the Ubuntu terminal by typing in NetBeans and I get the following error ->

```
 "WARNING: package com.sun.tools.javadoc.main not in jdk.javadoc
```

These are my installed Java Versions:

```
java -version
OpenJDK version "14.0.2" 2020-07-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 14.0.2+12-Ubuntu-120.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.2+12-Ubuntu-120.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: It seems you have an incomplete JDK installation. I am confused why you would install a "headless" JDK if you want to use a GUI (Swing) application.

Comment: What is "JRE Headless"?